# MySql - Sql query or procedure to generate report by transposing rows into columns

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot, pivot-table

This is the first time - I'm trying to do something like this - so please bear with me.
This is on MySql.

I am trying to generate a report to see which students have completed which topics and on which dates.

This is the current query that I run

```
select u.email,t.topic_name,tu.date_created as 'date completed'
from topic_user tu
join topic t ON tu.topic_id = t.topic_id
join user u ON tu.user_id = u.user_id
```

which will return results like

```
email         |    topic_name      |    date completed
abc@gmail.com |    ABC             |    03/01/2012
abc@gmail.com |    DEF             |    03/02/2012
abc@gmail.com |    ABC             |    03/08/2012
abc@gmail.com |    GHI             |    03/08/2012
def@gmail.com |    ABC             |    03/02/2012
def@gmail.com |    XYZ             |    03/10/2012
```

The way I want to generate the report is have the topic names as column headers and the date they completed it as values

```
email         |    ABC      |    DEF      |    GHI      |    JKL      |    XYZ     
abc@gmail.com | 03/08/2012  | 03/02/2012  | 03/08/2012  |    null     |    null
def@gmail.com | 03/02/2012  |    null     |    null     |    null     |  03/10/2012
```

Few things to note are:

1) All the topic names would come from the topic table - even if they have not been completed by the students - the value should appear as null

2) Incase of student abc@gmail.com - he has studied the topic ABC twice - but the report should get the latest date.

I guess I have to write a stored procedure to accomplish this. Like maybe first pull all the topic names from the topic table and then create a temp view and populate it.

I would appreciate any help you can provide.
Thanks much

Comment: Are the topic names fixed?  Could they be hardcoded inside sql? Are you guaranteed that you will only have one date_completed per topic name per email?

Comment: Yes the topic names are fixed in the sense when the course is created the topic table is populated with the names. New topics are added as and when needed. No as I mentioned, the same student can study the same topic multiple times but the report should show the last date. If you look at the abc@gmail.com student - he has completed the topic ABC twice but the report shows the last date. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've not tested this, and my experience with MySQL is limited but I hope the below is what you are after. It dynamically creates the `SELECT` statement using the `GROUP_CONCAT` function, then executes it (This is the bit I am not certain of the way to do it in MySQL).

```
SET @SQL = (
SELECT  CONCAT('SELECT Email,', GROUP_CONCAT(SelectText), ' FROM Topic_User tu INNER JOIN Users u ON u.User_ID = tu.User_ID GROUP BY Email')
FROM    (   SELECT  CONCAT(' MAX(CASE WHEN Topic_ID = ', Topic_ID, ' THEN tu.Date_Created END) AS `', Topic_Name, '`') AS SelectText
            FROM    Topic
        )  AS d);

PREPARE stmt FROM @SQL;
EXECUTE stmt
```

Of course if your topics are not changing very regularly you could just use:

```
SELECT  Email,
        MAX(CASE WHEN Topic_ID = 1 THEN tu.Date_Created END) AS ABC,
        MAX(CASE WHEN Topic_ID = 2 THEN tu.Date_Created END) AS DEF,
        MAX(CASE WHEN Topic_ID = 3 THEN tu.Date_Created END) AS GHI,
        MAX(CASE WHEN Topic_ID = 4 THEN tu.Date_Created END) AS JKL,
        MAX(CASE WHEN Topic_ID = 5 THEN tu.Date_Created END) AS XYZ
FROM    Topic_User tu
        INNER JOIN users u
            ON u.User_ID = tu.User_ID
GROUP BY Email
```

and alter the query each time a new topic is added (This is the query produced by the process above).

Comment: Nice solution. It should work fine as long as it is on MySQL >= 5.0.13

Comment: Thank you - I like the solution for when the topics are not changing regularly - but the database has about 90 odd topics and I would have to add all those cases. Your first solution of dynamically creating would have been ideal but I'm not able to get that to work - I'm getting the error - "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'to Banking, MAX(CASE WHEN topic_id = 3 THEN tu.date_created END) AS T' at line 1"

Comment: I expect this is to do with a `topic_name` with a space in. I've edited the solution to resolve this. if this is not it try selecting @SQL before running it, this will show you the query that has been generated, and should help you identify where the error is occuring.

Comment: If you change it to use backticks instead of single quotes it will work when there are single quotes in the text too.

Comment: @nnichols Good thinking. I've made that change now.

Comment: I think the problem is with the length limitation of group_concat - I printed the query and it is getting cut off and I'm getting the error "1260: 1 line(s) were cut by Group_Concat()"

Comment: Try increasing the max length for GROUP_CONCAT - `SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = val;`

Comment: yep that did the trick - This is the exact output I was looking for. You guys are absolutely great - GarethD thanks a lot for your time and nnichols appreciate your inputs - I had no idea how to get started on this. Thanks a bunch :)

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with a dynamically generated crosstab query. The query you want to end up with is something like this -

```
SELECT
    u.email,
    MAX(IF(t.topic_name = 'ABC', tu.date_created, NULL)) AS 'ABC',
    MAX(IF(t.topic_name = 'DEF', tu.date_created, NULL)) AS 'DEF',
    etc
FROM topic_user tu
INNER JOIN topic t
    ON tu.topic_id = t.topic_id
INNER JOIN user u
    ON tu.user_id = u.user_id
GROUP BY u.user_id;
```

So, in your server side language of choice you would dynamically build your field list based on first querying for a list of topics.

You could slightly reduce the overhead of this query by using the topic_ids instead of the topic_names so that you can drop the join to the topics table -

```
SELECT
    u.email,
    MAX(IF(tu.topic_id = 1, tu.date_created, NULL)) AS 'ABC',
    MAX(IF(tu.topic_id = 2, tu.date_created, NULL)) AS 'DEF',
    etc
FROM topic_user tu
INNER JOIN user u
    ON tu.user_id = u.user_id
GROUP BY u.user_id;
```

Comment: Thanks nichols - I am seeing if there is any way to avoid listing down the 90 odd topic names in the query and if there is anyway to dynamically pull them from the topic table

Comment: @Gublooo's method with the prepared statement is definitely better.